# How to annotate each line in the plot with the value of a specific column

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotations, label

I have the following function, which creates several time series for each 'prov_zona.' A time series for each plot in 'prov_zona'; see the figure attached for better understanding.

```
def createTimeSeriesPlot (df, index_metric):   # index metric: normalized_wetness_mean / normalized_nbr_mean   df_prov_zona_list = pd.unique(df['prov_zona'])    for item in df_prov_zona_list:
      df_pz = df.loc[df['prov_zona']==item].sort_values(by='year', ascending=True)
      df_pz = df_pz[['codigo_id', 'def_deco']]
      df_pz.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
      df_pz.sort_values(by='def_deco', ascending=True)

      df_plots_list = pd.unique(df_pz['codigo_id'])

      plt.figure(figsize=(10, 1.5), dpi=300)
      plt.title(item + ' - ' + index_metric, fontdict={'fontsize':8})

      def get_color(row):
        if row['def_deco'] == 'GRAVE (50-100%)':
            return 'red'
        elif row['def_deco'] == 'MEDIO ALTO (35-50%)':
            return 'orange'
        elif row['def_deco'] == 'MEDIO BAJO (20-35%)':
            return 'green'
        else:
            return 'black'

      for i in df_plots_list:
        df_plot = df.loc[df['codigo_id']==i].sort_values(by='year', ascending=True).set_index('year')
        color = df_plot.apply(get_color, axis=1)
        df_plot[index_metric].plot(color=color, xticks=years, linewidth=0.75, label=i)
      
      
      plt.xlabel("Años", fontdict={'fontsize': 8})
      plt.ylabel("TWC Normalizado", fontdict={'fontsize': 8})
      plt.xticks(fontsize=7)
      plt.yticks(fontsize=7)
      # plt.legend(loc=(1.01, 0), fontsize=5)
```

I want to show, for each line of each individual plot, the value of another column in the dataframe.

[image: time series plots]

In this case I want to show the value of variable "i" of the loop:

```
for i in df_plots_list:
        df_plot = df.loc[df['codigo_id']==i].sort_values(by='year', ascending=True).set_index('year')
        color = df_plot.apply(get_color, axis=1)
        df_plot[index_metric].plot(color=color, xticks=years, linewidth=0.75, label=i)
```

However, just adding the label as a parameter did not work.

Here there is a short example of the dataframe:

```
data = {
    'codigo_id': ['V5086M2_104', 'V5086M2_105', 'V5086M2_104', 'V5086M2_105', 'V5086M2_104', 'V5086M2_105', 'V5086M2_104', 'V5086M2_105', 'V5086M2_104', 'V5086M2_105', 'V5086M2_104', 'V5086M2_105', 'V5086M2_104', 'V5086M2_105', 'V5086M2_104', 'V5086M2_105'],
    'def_deco': ['NULO (0-20%)', 'NULO (0-20%)', 'NULO (0-20%)', 'NULO (0-20%)', 'NULO (0-20%)', 'NULO (0-20%)', 'NULO (0-20%)', 'NULO (0-20%)', 'NULO (0-20%)', 'NULO (0-20%)', 'NULO (0-20%)', 'NULO (0-20%)', 'NULO (0-20%)', 'NULO (0-20%)', 'NULO (0-20%)', 'NULO (0-20%)'],
    'year': [2022, 2022, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023],
    'prov_zona': ['Valencia_CasasDeMoya', 'Valencia_CasasDeMoya', 'Valencia_CasasDeMoya', 'Valencia_CasasDeMoya', 'Valencia_CasasDeMoya', 'Valencia_CasasDeMoya', 'Valencia_CasasDeMoya', 'Valencia_CasasDeMoya'],
    'normalized_wetness_mean': [0.512370105, 0.496375742, 0.487447416, 0.4748284, 0.487447416, 0.4748284, 0.487447416, 0.4748284]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

and How to call the function:

> createTimeSeriesPlot(df, 'normalized_wetness_mean')

Comment: Please provide a [mre]